# Is it possible to have a constant number in a spacial column of 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, parallel.for

I'm trying to improve the parallel.For in my main part of code. This loop has the main calculations and needs to be done more than 1 million times for each output (I need 80 million outputs). So any improvement even slightly can have an acute effect on the execution time.
I know that the IF condition can decrease the parallel calculation speed. Also, I know that may main variables (U[i,j] and V[i,j]) for special places are always zero. So if I could assign constant zero (don't want to change in calculation) for special columns of these arrays, I can eliminate IF condition from the code.

```
Before calculation:
| 1 1 1 0 1|
| 1 1 1 0 1|
| 1 1 1 0 1|
| 1 1 1 0 1|
After calculation:
| 3 1 8 0 5|
| 1 4 4 0 1|
| 7 3 1 0 8|
| 1 1 5 0 7|
```

I would like to have a column which its value stays always zero.

How can I assign constant number (zero) for spacial columns of a 2D array?

As a sample the aforementioned part look like:

```
double[,] U= new double[nx,ny];
double[,] V= new double[nx,ny];

Parallel.For(0,nx,i =>
{
   For (j=0; j<ny ; j++)
   {
     if (i!=a && i!=b &&i!=c &&i!=d &&)
     {
       U[i,j]= ...; // A big chunk of calculations
       V[i,j]=... ;// A big chunk of calculations
     }
  }
}
```

Interestingly, when I run the code I found out that it uses almost 20% of all cores. Is it because of my weak parallel loops or I should manually assign the number of cores to be used by the loop ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: locality of reference?

Comment: Have you ever heard of arrays having special columns?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: can we assign constant values to a column ?

Comment: @Mehdi: just a side note: "constant values" --- values by themselves are always constant. `42` always represents a number 42, you cannot mutate it.

Comment: No. Arrays are just simple sets of objects, organized by indexes. There's nothing "special" about them.

Comment: Do you mean that there is some column `x`, such that `U[i,x]` is always zero, for all values of `i`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders As you see in my code, I should ask For loop not to calculate spacial columns because they are zero. If loop calculates that columns they will take some data which is not correct. They should always be zero.

Comment: Ok, well there's no way of making an array that has special columns. You would have to change your algorithm to skip the columns you feel you should skip. However, I strongly suggest that you profile your code to find out where the time is being spent. It's quite possible you are trying to solve the wrong problem. In particular, it's possible that you have thread contention issues, and not a problem with too much CPU time being spent.

Comment: BTW, did you mean "spatial" column (having to do with space), or "special" column (having characteristics which differ from those of other columns)?

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't this be of some improvement?

```
Parallel.For(0,nx,i =>
{
   if (i!=a && i!=b &&i!=c &&i!=d &&)
   {
       For (j=0; j<ny ; j++)
       {
           U[i,j]= ...; // A big chunk of calculations
           V[i,j]=... ;// A big chunk of calculations
       }
   }
}
```

Evaluate the inner loop only if `i` doesn't have the condition satisfied. Otherwise you're in what is essentially a busy wait.

Comment: +1: I _am_ an idiot. It may or not be his big problem, and I was definitely thrown by the idea of special columns in an array, but, hey, `i` is invariant within that inner loop, so the `if` is invariant within that inner loop, so, of course, take it out of the inner loop!

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yeah I am not sure if this will help. I am thinking the compiler might be optimizing this already.

Comment: Also, I wonder if `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are the only indexes the OP wants to exclude? If there is a larger set, then conceivably `Parallel.ForEach` with an iterator returning index values might be better. Still, the true answer is, "profile, profile, profile".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: you right. It did not help. but it was interesting point. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Calculate borders in a separate kernel because only they have "if" clauses. Then calculate interiors without any if cnoditions. Expect 2x speed-up.

```
//interior (dont include borders)
Parallel.For(1,nx-1,i =>
{

       For (j=1; j<ny-1 ; j++)
       {
           U[i,j]= ...; // A big chunk of calculations
           V[i,j]=... ;// A big chunk of calculations
       } 

}

//exterior 1
Parallel.For(xx,xx1,i =>
{
   //another calculation
}

//exterior 2
Parallel.For(xx1,yy,i =>
{
   //another calculation
}

//exterior 3
Parallel.For(yy,yy1,i =>
{
   //another calculation
}

//exterior 4
Parallel.For(yy1,xx,i =>
{
   //another calculation
}
```

Use C++ dll for inner-loop to have 10x more speedup(SIMD) even opencl for gpgpu --> 30x speed-up.

Comment: the problem is the exception points in the calculation area are not in border. As you are familiar with physical concepts, I have a wall in the cavity, left side and right side of cavity has velocity but in the wall area velocity is zero. Therefore, I should always have zero velocity but in your first For loop you calculate velocity  for wall and wall effect cannot be shown in the calculations.
http://heattransfer.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/data/Journals/JHTRAO/27818/005706jhr1.jpeg

Comment: can you explain more how to use C++ dll in C# to have more speedup ?

Comment: Use dllexport in C++ and use dllimport in c# with proper C-space name